# Adding a runtime to Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am trying to add a runtime to Docker. The caveat is that it is [Docker Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Adoption).

Normally you add the runtime to the *deamon.json* file like shown in *[Docker runtime execution options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#docker-runtime-execution-options)*:

```json
{
  "runtimes": {
    "custom": {
      "path": "/path/to/runtime"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that Docker does not find that path, although I have it in my [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) distribution. Therefore, I suspect it's not looking inside the distribution for that path.

I also tried to add the binary to the other WSL distributions `docker-desktop` and  `docker-desktop-data` without success.

When I try to run a container, I get an error:

```
docker run --runtime=custom myapp
```

Output:

```
...
OCI runtime create failed:
fork/exec /path/to/runtime: no such file or directory: unknown
```